# Add icons to Listview using Arraylist

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have successfully created a listview that contains all the options (text). However I would like to add unique icons next to each of the options. How can I go about doing this, with my excising code?

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Here is my code:
AccountSettingsActivity.java

```
//All Options in Account Settings
private  void setupSettingsList(){
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.lvAccountSettings);

    ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
    options.add(getString((R.string.editProfile)));
    options.add(getString(R.string.notifications));
    options.add(getString(R.string.privacy_settings));
    options.add(getString(R.string.security));
    options.add(getString(R.string.ads));
    options.add(getString(R.string.help));
    options.add(getString(R.string.about));
    options.add(getString(R.string.logout));

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(mContext, R.layout.listview_row_adjustment, options);
    listView.setAdapter((adapter));
}
```

listview_row_adjustmnet.xml (This simply changes the text color and size of the options in the listview)

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listViewAdjustment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

Comment: this is a good example of what you need 
https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

Comment: You have to use a custom adapter for this purpose. You will have to create a custom adapter and set the adapter to the list view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A custom ListView with a custom adapter in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406084/a-custom-listview-with-a-custom-adapter-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Create Array in /res folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="images">
        <item>@drawable/img1</item>
        <item>@drawable/img2</item>
        <item>@drawable/img3</item>
    </array>

</resources>
```

update Account Setting:

```
    //All Options in Account Settings
    private  void setupSettingsList(){
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.lvAccountSettings);

TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);

        ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
        options.add(getString((R.string.editProfile)));
        options.add(getString(R.string.notifications));
        options.add(getString(R.string.privacy_settings));
        options.add(getString(R.string.security));
        options.add(getString(R.string.ads));
        options.add(getString(R.string.help));
        options.add(getString(R.string.about));
        options.add(getString(R.string.logout));
    // add images to adapter
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(mContext, R.layout.listview_row_adjustment, options, images);
        listView.setAdapter((adapter));
    }
```

Add Image View in listview_row_adjustmnet.xml

in Adapter set the image:

```
imageView.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(i, -1));
```

Comment: thank you for your response, could you please elaborate on the "in Adapter set the image" part, i cant seem to understand what you are referring to.

Comment: hi you will be making a custom adapter for that

Comment: im very new to this, could you show me how that would be done?

Comment: https://www.devglan.com/android/create-custom-adapter-in-list-view

Comment: Check this link

Answer (score 0):

Use a data model with title and icon like below

```
class Data {

 public int imageId;
 public String txt;

 Data(Drawable imageId, String text) {

   this.imageId = imageId;
  this.txt = text;
}
```

}

```
Data menuItemSearch = new Data(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_search_orange), resources.getString(R.string.title))
```

and when set drawable in image use this one

```
yourImage.setImageDrawable(data.imageId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You have to add in your listview_row_adjustmnet.xml.

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listViewAdjustment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

And for Code AccountSettingActivity class:

```
private  void setupSettingsList(){
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.lvAccountSettings);

ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();


options.add(getString((R.string.editProfile)));
options.add(getString(R.string.notifications));
options.add(getString(R.string.privacy_settings));
options.add(getString(R.string.security));
options.add(getString(R.string.ads));
options.add(getString(R.string.help));
options.add(getString(R.string.about));
options.add(getString(R.string.logout));
ArrayList<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<>();
//Please add Customized addapter 
}
```

for the customized adapter, you find help in this Link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YF6ocdPaBg.

To set an ImageView in code Please see this answer [Using variable to change image in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964394/usingvariable-to-change-image-in-java).

Comment: The ArrayAdapter<string> line doesn't make any sense.. gives me a bunch of errors

Comment: Check this <https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView > this Link may help you.